# How can I delay my aliens' laser shots to fire shortly after they enter the view?

Tags: sprite-kit

As my app stands right now, each alien fires once immediately once it enters the view. Based on the code below, how can I edit to allow each alien to shoot shortly after it enters the view instead of immediately upon `[self addChild...]` ?? I'm not picky on time timing per say, I'd just like to randomize it a bit. Thanks!

```
    alienLaser = [_alienLasers objectAtIndex:_nextAlienLaser];

    _nextAlienLaser++;


    if (_nextAlienLaser >= _alienLasers.count) _nextAlienLaser = 0;

    alienLaser.position = ccpAdd(alien.position, ccp(alienLaser.contentSize.width/8, 0));
    alienLaser.visible = YES;
    [alienLaser stopAllActions];
    [alienLaser runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                           [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:300 position:ccp(winSize.width, -100000)],
                           [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)],
                           nil]];
```

Comment: You could use `sleep();` and input a random integer say between 1-5.

Comment: Tried it. Last time I did... it seemed to disrupt a lot of things. Is that not necessarily an orthodox method?

Comment: Well `sleep` runs on the main thread which could interrupt other processes also running on the main thread. In fact it stops all execution on the main thread. It also stops all UI interaction. What I would suggest is running it on a background thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use sleep.  That would be a horrible idea.  Run a search for 'sleep' and see what they say about it.  Instead, just create a wait action.  Then add that action to your sequence along with others.

```
SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5];
SKAction *seq = [SKAction sequence:@[wait,shoot,move]];
[alienLaser runAction:seq];
```